# Does Yosemite 10.10.5 comes with nginx?

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, nginx

I am a little confused why a fresh Yosemite 10.10.5 seems to have a nginx process.

If I issue the command `ps ax | grep "nginx"` or `ps aux|grep nginx`

I get:

```
1266 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep nginx
```

Some seconds later `ps ax | grep "nginx"` returns:

```
1280 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep nginx
```

If I try:

```
ps -lef|grep -i nginx:|awk '{ print $2}'|xargs kill -9
```

I get:

```
kill: 1291: No such process
```

The process is always closing and opening a new process.

Activity Monitor does not show any nginx process.

Is this normal?
Why do I get this in a fresh OS X install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is perfectly expected behavior,** but perhaps somewhat confusing if you don't know exactly what the commands involved actually do. And no, **there's no rogue software involved.** I will try to explain what's actually happening here.

First, when you run `ps ax` that gives you a list of all processes that are running on the system, and (some of) their command line arguments.

Second, when you run `grep "nginx"` that will read from its standard input (as you did not provide a file to be used as input) and output any lines that contain the string `nginx`.

In the shell of a Unix-like system (such as Mac OS X), pipes are generally implemented in a way that, very basically, means that *commands are started from right to left, but data is transported from left to right.*

**So, here's what happens:** First `grep` is started, with the argument `nginx`. Second, `ps` is started with the argument `ax`, and its standard output is tied to the standard input of the `grep` process. As `ps` runs, its output is fed to the standard output of `ps`, which is *the same thing* as the standard input of `grep`. In turn, `grep` looks at each line, looking for the string `nginx`, because that is what you told `grep` to do. Such a line appears once: *the grep process itself with its command-line arguments!* As a result, this line is printed by `grep` to *grep's* standard output, and all other are suppressed. In your first example, grep's standard output isn't tied into any other process, so by default it is printed to the terminal. When there is no more data from `ps`, then `grep` also exits because all of the commands are tied together; it doesn't make any real sense to have one of them executing when another has finished.

When you pipe the output of grep through `awk` into `xargs kill`, what happens is that xargs builds a list of what it is going to do, but doesn't actually do it until the end. So by the time xargs gets around to invoking kill, the grep process -- which had the nginx among its command line parameters -- is already gone. Hence there is no process to send a signal to, and `kill` notifies you of this fact.

As you can see, there is no rogue nginx process running on your system evading your attempts to find it; there's only grep, which is started repeatedly, once for each time you look, which finds itself.

You can avoid this by using character groups somewhere in the search string, because that won't find itself. For example, `ps ax | grep foobar` returns the grep process, but `ps ax | grep 'fooba[r]'` doesn't, because `fooba[r]` isn't the same thing as `foobar` when compared as a plain string. (`[r]` matches any one of the characters `r`, so only `r`.) Note that in order to do this you probably have to escape the argument to `grep`.

As an aside, it's almost always unnecessary to first run `grep` and then `awk` without anything else in between. Instead of `... | grep 'foobar' | awk '{ print $2 }'` for some preceding command `...`, you can simply use `... | awk '/foobar/ { print $2 }'` to have awk perform both duties. This is most often encountered with `cat`, where it is called [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), but the concept generalizes well to other commands as well, such as grep in your case.

Comment: So if nginx was really running we should get an output with two lines , one for the grep process and other to nginx process itself , correct ?

Comment: @DesignT With the command given in the question you should in that case see two or more lines, depending on nginx's architecture and how OS X's `ps` handles processes with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nginx installed/running as a process.

You could replace nginx with something entirely made up and get the same result:

```
ps ax | grep "boatymcboatface"
```